# How to disable android's status bar scroll down animation?

Tags: java, android, uistatusbar

Even in a Samsung Galaxy Note 2, when you pull down the scroll bar, it takes some time to shown down and if you did not pulled it enough it comes back to the top (hides again).

So how do we disable this unnecessary animation (in consideration that it does not opens in a half)?

Do we have to make a program with some tricks in java or is there an app that does that already?

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail? Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: EASI is asking about Samsung's edge-swipe gesture to reveal the statusbar even in apps that have hidden it.

Comment: When you press your finger on the upper status bar and slide it down to show the full screen status. You have to slide to at least half screen to work. It would be easier and faster if we could just click on the status bar to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this question, paste next code before code setContextView(...)

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
```

It works fine for me!